# How to monitor what happens over an SSH session?

Tags: ssh

I have a network device (a scanner) that can scan to SFTP.  Unfortunately, it's giving me problems.  I can see from the SSH logs that it's able to login, but I can't see what it's doing after that. I think it's running into a file or directory not found situation.  The device has no verbose logging capability.  So I have to do this on the server somehow.

How can I monitor/log what happens after it has successfully establish an SSH connection?

Comment: What is this device? Does it have shell access, can you run `strace` and restart the SSH daemon? Can you not run `sshd` more verbosely and/or run it in the foreground?

Comment: I see why the confusion. I amended the question.  It's a scanner. It uses SFTP.  I can run strace and restart the ssh daemon. I'll see what it does.

Comment: I just did a bit ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this solution from the RHEL forums titled: [How to configure SSH to debug mode?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/295863)

#### Method #1 - sshd on another port

```
$ /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -D -p (port) 2>&1
```

Then to connect to it:

```
$ ssh -p (port)
```

#### Method #2 - change sshd's config file

```
$ vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Then change the loglevel:

```
LogLevel DEBUG3
```

And then restart `sshd`.

```
$ service sshd restart
```

*sshd_config man page*

```
$ man sshd_config
...
LogLevel:

Gives the verbosity level that is used when logging messages from sshd.  
The possible values are: QUIET, FATAL, ERROR, INFO, VER-BOSE, DEBUG, DEBUG1, 
DEBUG2 and DEBUG3. The default is INFO. DEBUG and DEBUG1 are equivalent. DEBUG2 
and DEBUG3 each specify higher levels of debugging output. Logging with a DEBUG 
level violates the privacy of users and is not recommended.
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to enable TTY logging so it shows up in audit logs

```
echo "session     required      pam_tty_audit.so enable=*" >> /etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac
echo "session     required      pam_tty_audit.so enable=*" >> /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac
```

Then, to view the logs you can use:

```
aureport --tty
```